# Need help with file IO in C

Tags: c#, c, file-io

I'm converting the following code from C# to C, and I don't think I'm doing this correctly.

`Entry3D` and `entry_3d` are just structs that contain `int lookup, length, extra` in both cases.
Here's the C# snippet (and it works perfectly fine):

```
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open("artidx.mul", FileMode.Open));
    BinaryReader art = new BinaryReader(File.Open("art.mul", FileMode.Open));
    int count = (int)(reader.BaseStream.Length / 12);
    int length = 0x10000;
    Entry3D[] index = new Entry3D[length];
    Console.WriteLine("Loading indexes {0}", count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count && i < length; i++)
    {
        index[i].lookup = reader.ReadInt32();
        index[i].length = reader.ReadInt32();
        index[i].extra = reader.ReadInt32();
    }
    for (int i = count; i < length; ++i)
    {
        index[i].lookup = -1; 
        index[i].length = -1;
        index[i].extra = -1;
    }
```

Here's the part in C that I'm having trouble with.

```
/* Init everything else */
printf( "Init maps & gfx" );
mapFile = fopen( "sd:/map0.mul",   "rb" ), 
 artIdx = fopen( "sd:/artidx.mul", "rb" ),
    art = fopen( "sd:/art.mul",    "rb" );

if ( mapFile == NULL || artIdx == NULL || art == NULL )
{
  printf( "D'oh, file loading failed: [%d][%d][%d]", mapFile == NULL, artIdx == NULL, art == NULL  );
  return(1);
}

/* Find artidx count and set length */
printf( "Init art index" );
fseek( artIdx, 0, SEEK_END ); 
int count = (ftell(artIdx) / 12), length = 0x10000; // 0x10000 entries availible
entry_3d entries[length];
fseek( artIdx, 0, SEEK_SET );

printf( "Reading art-idx, count=%d", count );
int i;
for( i = 0; i < count && i < length; i++ )
{
  //printf( "loc: %u i: %u", ftell( artIdx ), i );
  //fread( &entries[i], 12, 1, artIdx );
  fread( &(entries[i].lookup), 4, 1, artIdx ); // read 12 bytes total
  fread( &(entries[i].length), 4, 1, artIdx );
  fread( &(entries[i].extra), 4, 1, artIdx );
}

printf( "Setting aidx remainders" );
for ( i = count; i < length; i++ )
{
  entries[i].lookup = -1; 
  entries[i].length = -1;
  entries[i].extra = -1;
}
```

It's a bit impossible for me to debug the C part, but I can tell that it "dies" somewhere in the first for-loop. I'm guessing that it's possibly reading past the end of the stream (even though it shouldn't)?

Comment: Why is it impossible to debug the C?  Just run it in the debugger until it crashes; the debugger should tell you what line you reached.

Comment: @Kevin: What platform are you running on?  If you're on Linux (or equivalent), try GDB.  If you're in Windows and developing in VS, just use the built-in VS debugger.

Comment: Using Windows but compiling for Wii (and I don't think some libraries I'm using will compile w/ Windows).

Comment: @Kevin: Then you really need to find yourself a debugger (I don't know anything about developing for Wii, but I'm sure there will be a good toolkit).  It's insanity to try and develop code without being able to step through it.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth:...or you could write some unit tests.....

Comment: What do your debugging printf's tell you?  Are you sure `sizeof(int) == 4` on your platform?

Comment: @Mitch: I of course endorse unit tests to detect symptoms, but they're no replacement for line-by-line debugging to determine causes!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: true!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see much wrong here. The code will work correctly on a linux/windows box.

Error handling could be improved.

It will not fail gracefully when the artidx file is not a multiple of 12 bytes.

I suppose this code could quite easily run out of memory on the Wii console. Try allocating the entry_3d array dynamically (using calloc/malloc). Also, try reducing the length to see whether you are running out of memory. It is not impossible that the libc implementation on the Wii doesn't warn you when stack will overlap heap; embedded systems sometimes assume the programmers know all the intricacies and limits of the device (The Wii with it's many processing chips is a very fine example of that in many respects, so I'd really consider this).

I'm pretty sure you know how to find the forums where the homebrew devs lurk. They might be able to shed some light here.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to a debugger, you can add some `printf` statements inside the loop to see how far it gets before it dies.  Add something like `printf("i == %i\n", i);` at the top of each loop iteration.  Also, save the return value of `fread` to a variable and print it out as well (for each `fread` call).  When the program dies, this should at least leave a trail of bread crumbs that you can follow.

Also, check the return value of your `fopen` and `fseek` calls and make sure that they returned successfully.

Comment: I tried `printf`ing it, and it gets to `i=9834` before the next lines just print `l&` without any of my formatting, then after a few hundred lines of `l&` the program crashes.